# xsl counting and xpath syntax

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, xpath

I have a table of projects created in SharePoint 2010. I am trying to create reporting for management and need to get counts of various fields. I have used xsl to get the values of fields when viewing single items, so I am fairly familiar with the language. However, I cannot find a good explanation of the syntax for counting multiple items.

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="ms-vb2">
        Project Title
    </th>
    <th class="ms-vb2">
        Project Leader
    </th>
    <th class="ms-vb2">
        Project Status
    </th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Project Title 1
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Project Leader 1
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Completed
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Project Title 2
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Project Leader 1
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Withdrawn
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Project Title 3
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Project Leader 2
    </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        Completed
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--About 100 more rows-->
</table>
```

There is a lot of nesting going on, so I am having difficulty targeting specific areas and I have very little control over the html due to this being generated by SharePoint.

Here is the reporting table I am trying to create using XSL:

```
<table id="FourBlockerHead" class="ClearBlockFloat">
  <tr>
    <th>Completed Count</th>
    <th>Withdrawn Count</th>
    <th>On Hold Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../td[@ms-vb2='Completed'])" /><!--Should be 2-->
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../td[@ms-vb2='Withdrawn'])" /><!--Should be 1-->
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../td[@ms-vb2='On Hold'])" /><!--Should be 0-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know there is a problem with my XPATH syntax, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of what the source XML looks like? Or are you trying to process HTML as XML and apply XSL to it?

Comment: @Ryan you didn't close square brackets

Comment: @Stevangelista That might actually be my problem. Can you not apply XSL to HTML? I have another page that accesses certain fields (in the same SharePoint) and formats them into a nice presentation page. So I figured I could use XSL in this way as well. My long-term plan is to use these "counts" combined with others to create bar and graph charts using JavaScript.

Comment: @Ryan Is your question not answered?

Comment: @michael.hor257k No, it is not. I am still unsure if this is something that is possible.

Comment: @Ryan Of course it's possible - see the full stylesheet I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../td[@ms-vb2='Completed')" />
```

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//td[@class='ms-vb2'][normalize-space()='Completed'])" />
```

and likewise for the other two.

**Notes**:

- You did not provide the context, so I have changed the path to an absolute one, that counts all nodes in the entire document;
- You don't have an attribute named `ms-vb2`;
- You need to trim the whitespace in the data cell before comparing ot to a string with no whitespace.

---

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <table id="FourBlockerHead" class="ClearBlockFloat">
        <tr>
            <th>Completed Count</th>
            <th>Withdrawn Count</th>
            <th>On Hold Count</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//td[@class='ms-vb2'][normalize-space()='Completed'])" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//td[@class='ms-vb2'][normalize-space()='Withdrawn'])" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//td[@class='ms-vb2'][normalize-space()='On Hold'])" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input example, will return:

```
<table id="FourBlockerHead" class="ClearBlockFloat">
   <tr>
      <th>Completed Count</th>
      <th>Withdrawn Count</th>
      <th>On Hold Count</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete XSLT would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/table">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table id="FourBlockerHead" class="ClearBlockFloat" border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Completed Count</th>
            <th>Withdrawn Count</th>
            <th>On Hold Count</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="tr">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(td[@class='ms-vb2' and normalize-space(text())='Completed'])" /><!--Should be 2-->
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(td[@class='ms-vb2' and normalize-space(text())='Withdrawn'])" /><!--Should be 1-->
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(td[@class='ms-vb2' and normalize-space(text())='On Hold'])" /><!--Should be 0-->
            </td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can include this in your source XML file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="source.xslt"?>
```

in your XML file to get a well formatted HTML output.

The **output** would look like this:

[image]